# How can I replace "class" in class.function() with a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm using **Python 3.5** for this. So the title is very confusing, I'm still new to python and don't really know how to solve that problem, nor how to give it a proper title as you can see. I do see where my logic flawed me (how the heck did i intend to just replace that argument with another word so easily is beyond me) but I still don't know what the solution is. So basically my problem is trying to run something like this:

```
def attack(self,target):
    target.hp -= self.attack
```

This obviously doesn't work when I try to call it from my permanent game loop:

```
opponent = Enemy()
player = Enemy()

if action == "a":
    player.attack(opponent)
```

And I get a error of:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I'll paste the entire code just so you guys can have a better look at this. Also, I'd appreciate any tips to what else can be adjusted in the code to make it better. There it is, thanks in advance!

```
import sys
import random

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, attack):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.attack = attack

    def attack(self,target):
        target.hp -= self.attack
        print(target.name +" just lost" + str(self.attack)+"HP")

    def status(self):
        if self.hp <= 0:
            print(self.name +' has just died!')
            sys.exit(0)

        print(self.name +"'s HP:" +str(self.hp))


opponent = Enemy("Goblin",10,1)
player = Enemy("Player",10,2)

while True:
    attackChance = random.randrange(0,2)
    if attackChance == 0:
        print(opponent.name + ": Damn it!\n")
    else:
        opponent.attack(player)

    action = input('Press "a" to attack')
    if action == "a":
        player.attack(opponent)
    else:
        continue

    player.status()
    opponent.status()
```

Comment: `self.attack = attack` is overwriting your method.

Comment: Don't use the same names for properties and methods.

Comment: Methods are just properties that happen to hold functions. So you can't use the same name for both things.

Comment: Yeah I kinda understand that by now. What I want to know is how to get around it and make that piece of code above work.

Edit: nvm im stupid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I see what happened. You declared both an attribute `self.attack` and a function `self.attack`. When you initialized `self.attack` in the constructor, you overwrote the function -- when you write `player.attack(opponent)`, Python is trying to call a number, which results in an error.

To fix this, just rename either the attribute or the function.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense, and it actually works, so I had the right idea all along. Thanks for pointing this out, didn't really understand what the commenters meant.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by making `attack` a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). Then inside the class you'll need to reference the value as a private attribute `self._attack`, but users/clients of the class can continue to use `attack` as an `Enemy` instance method.

Here's what I mean (with comments to further help explain):

```
import random
import sys

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, attack):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self._attack = attack

    @property
    def attack(self):  # getter
        return self._do_attack  # return method

    @attack.setter
    def attack(self, attack):
        self._attack = attack  # change value

    def _do_attack(self, target):
        target.hp -= self._attack  # doesn't use property
        print(target.name +" just lost" + str(self._attack)+"HP")

    def status(self):
        if self.hp <= 0:
            print(self.name +' has just died!')
            sys.exit(0)

        print(self.name +"'s HP:" +str(self.hp))


opponent = Enemy("Goblin",10,1)
player = Enemy("Player",10,2)

while True:
    attackChance = random.randrange(0,2)
    if attackChance == 0:
        print(opponent.name + ": Damn it!\n")
    else:
        opponent.attack(player)

    action = input('Press "a" to attack')
    if action == "a":
        player.attack(opponent)
    else:
        continue

    player.status()
    opponent.status()

action = ''
opponent = Enemy()
player = Enemy()

if action == "a":
    player.attack(opponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename `self.attack` to something else. E.g., `self.attack_points`.